4.2.0 - Both my Add-Ons menu and my Extensions menu are blank upon updating
I updated my version of Blender, loaded my settings from the previous version, and now my Add-ons menu, and the new Extensions menu are both completely and utterly blank.
I've looked in the console log but found nothing that could point me to it. I've deleted a few addons that've been producing proper errors, but there's still nothing.

https://pastebin.com/m6iyCgD9 - Console Log

Ah, finally figured it out.
It's because "System: Blender Extensions" was disabled in my filter by default. For SOME REASON

It's always a good idea to thoroughly read the release notes before switching to a new version. Then you'll see stuff like this that will clue you in to what's in store. Blender is switching to an online addon platform.

Nah, I was more than aware of that fact. What I WASN'T aware of was that the new extension system is by itself being treated AS an addon and as such, it was by default filtered out by my workspace settings as "brand new unknown addon" >>
